# why does my hangman code keep coming back with an error saying " IndexError: list index out of range"

Tags: python

here is my code
my assignment is to create a hangman game that picks word from an outside text file, pick a word, close the file, then start the game. I think the problem is with opening the text file. I'm not sure if I'm saving it in the right spot or whatever. pls help.

```
    import random
#extract a random word from a text file

def word_selected(fname):
    word_file = open('hangman list.txt','r+')
    secret_word = random.choice(word_file.read().split())
    word_file.close()
    return secret_word
secret_word = word_selected('hangman list.txt')
print(secret_word)
#Display randomly chosen word in dash:
def word_selected_dashed():
    word_selected_dashed = []
    for i in range(len(secret_word)):
        word_selected_dashed.append('_')
    return ''.join(word_selected_dashed)

word_selected_dashed = word_selected_dashed()
print(word_selected_dashed)

trials = 5

gussed_word = list(word_selected_dashed)

while trials > 0:
    if ''.join(gussed_word) == secret_word:
        print("Congraluation, you have gussed the correct word")
        break

    print('you have got '+ str(trials)+ ' wrong tries ')
    user_guseed_letter = input('Guess a letter >>>>> \n')


    if user_guseed_letter in secret_word:
        print('Correct!')
        for i in range(len(secret_word)):
            if list(secret_word)[i] == user_guseed_letter:
                gussed_word[i] = user_guseed_letter
        print(''.join(gussed_word))

    elif user_guseed_letter not in secret_word:
        print('wrong!')
        trials -= 1
        hang = display_hangman(tries=(5-trials))
        print(hang)
if trials == 0 :
    print('you have ran out of trials')
```

Comment: Can you share the stacktrace ? (the full error message, not just the type of error, this will tell at which line you get the error)

Comment: Yes, please tell us exactly what error it is giving you, why doesn't your existing code work.

Comment: ok here is the full error message : Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\C.Schubart\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Hangman 2.py", line 9, in <module>
    secret_word = word_selected('hangman list.txt')
  File "C:\Users\C.Schubart\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Hangman 2.py", line 6, in word_selected
    secret_word = random.choice(word_file.read().split())
  File "C:\Users\C.Schubart\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\random.py", line 378, in choice
    return seq[self._randbelow(len(seq))]
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: hope that helps

Answer (score 1):

- One issue I notice is in the `word_selected` function, you have an input of `fname`, then use a specific file name within the function. Instead of writing out the actual file name, use the variable you used in the function name (ie `fname`).
- Also, make sure the file is in the same directory (folder) of your Python file. If its in a different directory, you can also specify the whole file path as the file name.

Comment: thank you x 10000000000000. you helped me so much. i switched the filename to the folder path and that fixed it. really appreciate it